# Why is HighCharts not recognizing my data properly?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, key-value

**GOAL:**
Plot the JSON data on a scatter plot. Each object contain 3 values but the last (the array of IDs) should be ignored -- it is not necessary to represent it on the graph.

**PROBLEM:**
It seems that HighCharts is not recognizing my x-data. It will not scale the x-axis (datetime) according to my data. It **does** understand my y-values. And it is represented in the graph.

**WHAT ARE YOU DOING?**
I'm taking a JSON string, using JSON.parse() on it, making the dates like YYYY-MM-DD instead of UTC, then I'm giving `myArray['vector']` to HighChart's `data` key.

**THOUGHTS:**
I believe this is related to how I'm structuring the JSON string or how I'm passing it to the key/value pair `data`. I'm a bit confused as to how JSON data should be 'translated' to a key/value pair.

Below is the result. Note how the x-axis has no ticks. The values are also in order of their position of the array (not by their date)

[image: The result. Note how the x-axis has no ticks. The values are also in order of their position of the array (not by their date)]

**JSON:**

```
{
   "vector":[
              [
                 "2017-06-06T04:31:16.000Z",
                 0.42,
                 [
                    "10155104233200659_10155105320445659",
                    "10155107157865659_10155107413550659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155101259520659",
                    "10155098835305659_10155101265245659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155101191290659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155101285415659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155101300165659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155101337070659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155101354640659",
                    "1558728630806541_1561351187210952",
                    "10155101928310659_10155102129290659",
                    "10155100854365659",
                    "10155101928310659_10155102183210659",
                    "10155101455910659_10155101458430659",
                    "1561546217191449_1561590010520403",
                    "10155101455910659_10155101459025659",
                    "10155101455910659_10155101461415659",
                    "10155101455910659_10155102138275659",
                    "10155101928310659_10155102150395659",
                    "10155101455910659_10155101462715659",
                    "870299173970694144",
                    "10155101455910659_10155101466670659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155101699660659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155102227220659",
                    "10155100854365659_10155102338105659",
                    "10155101928310659_10155102363275659",
                    "10155101455910659_10155101723225659",
                    "1561432737202797",
                    "10155101928310659_10155102372445659",
                    "10155101455910659_10155101481925659"
                 ]
              ],
              [
                 "2017-06-01T03:06:45.000Z",
                 0.47,
                 [
                    "10155078962635659_10155088932395659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086203305659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086234940659",
                    "10155085853500659_10155089736675659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086284290659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086294655659",
                    "868637256197840896",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086299195659",
                    "10155089549730659_10155089737300659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086390050659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086391925659",
                    "10155080256225659_10155089749815659",
                    "10155089549730659_10155090102235659",
                    "10155089549730659_10155090105425659",
                    "10155089549730659_10155090154310659",
                    "10155089549730659_10155090160515659",
                    "10155089549730659_10155090191730659",
                    "10155089549730659_10155090365070659",
                    "10155041106080659_10155086572640659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086121160659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086155370659",
                    "10155085853500659_10155086166860659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086173400659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086176665659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086186500659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086189325659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086193075659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086197225659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155086635920659",
                    "10155086108505659_10155087687155659"
                 ]
              ],
              [
                 "2017-05-26T03:32:24.000Z",
                 0.43,
                 [
                    "10155076988775659_10155077020050659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077018590659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077016610659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077018385659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077016860659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077016865659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077018410659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077016530659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077015135659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017130659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077016630659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077015210659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077015205659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077018990659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077015255659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017270659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077013155659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077016690659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077019325659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017305659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017385659",
                    "10155076677150659_10155077073125659",
                    "10155076677150659_10155077036660659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017615659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077019365659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017695659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017680659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017780659",
                    "10155076988775659_10155077017760659",
                    "10155076568000659_10155077074260659"
                 ]
              ],
              [
                 "2017-05-07T03:02:04.000Z",
                 0.8,
                 [
                    "15a1e146e7ed603aecbe16de25ed53fc",
                    "10155015378740659_10155015486550659",
                    "10155011834555659_10155013722600659",
                    "10155015378740659_10155015483050659",
                    "10155012171695659_10155022393165659",
                    "859973050628026368",
                    "860299410340630528",
                    "860096826610941952",
                    "859989850455408642",
                    "7d79e45313c878ec78a0b34de60c69f3",
                    "860127021120327680",
                    "860300107266138112",
                    "860311173073391617",
                    "860312531407163393",
                    "860316615765876736",
                    "860156681401114626",
                    "860317260409257985",
                    "Qd_q0XF0Y10",
                    "860166160851099649",
                    "860190399180222466",
                    "860204548777889792",
                    "860211634886901760",
                    "1529799180366153_1532172110128860",
                    "860269305077870592",
                    "860287769960165376",
                    "860297098775982082",
                    "860162336727977985",
                    "10155014502490659_10155016027360659",
                    "1532221810123890_1533617433317661",
                    "10155015378740659_10155015420560659"
                 ]
              ],
              [
                 "2017-05-04T03:08:33.000Z",
                 0.55,
                 [
                    "10155005822955659_10155006234215659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006238455659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006194705659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006241065659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006241655659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006177605659",
                    "10155005114840659_10155006201270659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006091430659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006095520659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006099105659",
                    "10155002652900659_10155006101040659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006101600659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006109155659",
                    "10155002652900659_10155006110655659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006113965659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006132275659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006139910659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006142495659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006143850659",
                    "10154997175925659_10155006178085659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006148580659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006190080659",
                    "10155005114840659_10155006154345659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006154825659",
                    "10155005114840659_10155006167935659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006157700659",
                    "10155005114840659_10155006160225659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006231175659",
                    "10155005609550659_10155006187295659",
                    "10155005822955659_10155006162850659"
                 ]
              ],
              [
                 "2017-05-02T03:01:57.000Z",
                 0.49,
                 [
                    "874302750531694592",
                    "851862555752640513",
                    "851862767925637120",
                    "874318907250757634",
                    "874329266107936768",
                    "874335249144086531",
                    "851870647521341443",
                    "874107458871894021",
                    "851772861501059072",
                    "874355138969956352",
                    "874250856476139520",
                    "874274312253034496",
                    "874278730088280066",
                    "874356894428798977",
                    "851893814474264576",
                    "874666827904937985",
                    "851923766158520320",
                    "851891395493101568",
                    "874684725188845572",
                    "874685434911236098",
                    "874391730396708864",
                    "874396116737019909",
                    "874737533766311937",
                    "874799536073519104",
                    "874817322791313409",
                    "851892924115582977",
                    "874396860777091072",
                    "874551209625100288",
                    "874558005903335424",
                    "874609184905588736"
                 ]
              ],
              [
                 "2017-04-11T03:04:21.000Z",
                 0.54,
                 [
                    "872880479300603905",
                    "872905370355855361",
                    "872914304227475460",
                    "872661418985877506",
                    "872662404416638976",
                    "872922590024794115",
                    "872923180117241856",
                    "872967240488034305",
                    "872980087943176193",
                    "872989868145741829",
                    "872997173008486402",
                    "872880235649392640",
                    "873003042869792790",
                    "872941776868433921",
                    "873004432853696512",
                    "872841099542450178",
                    "872767600647954435",
                    "872819121804726272",
                    "872940586894061568",
                    "872985706150350848",
                    "872762907746066432",
                    "872869944161165312",
                    "872880243824103424",
                    "872846343147999233",
                    "873015156883812353",
                    "872938894320390145",
                    "872655599145824256",
                    "873351602639384576",
                    "873352989515403264",
                    "ea4b7c58ceee69909aad70a8d25f46ef"
                 ]
              ]
   ]
}
```

**JavaScript and HighCharts initialization:**

```
var myJSON = '{"vector":[["2017-06-06T04:31:16.000Z",0.42,["10155104233200659_10155105320445659","10155107157865659_10155107413550659","10155100854365659_10155101259520659","10155098835305659_10155101265245659","10155100854365659_10155101191290659","10155100854365659_10155101285415659","10155100854365659_10155101300165659","10155100854365659_10155101337070659","10155100854365659_10155101354640659","1558728630806541_1561351187210952","10155101928310659_10155102129290659","10155100854365659","10155101928310659_10155102183210659","10155101455910659_10155101458430659","1561546217191449_1561590010520403","10155101455910659_10155101459025659","10155101455910659_10155101461415659","10155101455910659_10155102138275659","10155101928310659_10155102150395659","10155101455910659_10155101462715659","870299173970694144","10155101455910659_10155101466670659","10155100854365659_10155101699660659","10155100854365659_10155102227220659","10155100854365659_10155102338105659","10155101928310659_10155102363275659","10155101455910659_10155101723225659","1561432737202797","10155101928310659_10155102372445659","10155101455910659_10155101481925659"]],["2017-06-01T03:06:45.000Z",0.47,["10155078962635659_10155088932395659","10155086108505659_10155086203305659","10155086108505659_10155086234940659","10155085853500659_10155089736675659","10155086108505659_10155086284290659","10155086108505659_10155086294655659","868637256197840896","10155086108505659_10155086299195659","10155089549730659_10155089737300659","10155086108505659_10155086390050659","10155086108505659_10155086391925659","10155080256225659_10155089749815659","10155089549730659_10155090102235659","10155089549730659_10155090105425659","10155089549730659_10155090154310659","10155089549730659_10155090160515659","10155089549730659_10155090191730659","10155089549730659_10155090365070659","10155041106080659_10155086572640659","10155086108505659_10155086121160659","10155086108505659_10155086155370659","10155085853500659_10155086166860659","10155086108505659_10155086173400659","10155086108505659_10155086176665659","10155086108505659_10155086186500659","10155086108505659_10155086189325659","10155086108505659_10155086193075659","10155086108505659_10155086197225659","10155086108505659_10155086635920659","10155086108505659_10155087687155659"]],["2017-05-26T03:32:24.000Z",0.43,["10155076988775659_10155077020050659","10155076988775659_10155077018590659","10155076988775659_10155077016610659","10155076988775659_10155077018385659","10155076988775659_10155077016860659","10155076988775659_10155077016865659","10155076988775659_10155077018410659","10155076988775659_10155077016530659","10155076988775659_10155077015135659","10155076988775659_10155077017130659","10155076988775659_10155077016630659","10155076988775659_10155077015210659","10155076988775659_10155077015205659","10155076988775659_10155077018990659","10155076988775659_10155077015255659","10155076988775659_10155077017270659","10155076988775659_10155077013155659","10155076988775659_10155077016690659","10155076988775659_10155077019325659","10155076988775659_10155077017305659","10155076988775659_10155077017385659","10155076677150659_10155077073125659","10155076677150659_10155077036660659","10155076988775659_10155077017615659","10155076988775659_10155077019365659","10155076988775659_10155077017695659","10155076988775659_10155077017680659","10155076988775659_10155077017780659","10155076988775659_10155077017760659","10155076568000659_10155077074260659"]],["2017-05-07T03:02:04.000Z",0.8,["15a1e146e7ed603aecbe16de25ed53fc","10155015378740659_10155015486550659","10155011834555659_10155013722600659","10155015378740659_10155015483050659","10155012171695659_10155022393165659","859973050628026368","860299410340630528","860096826610941952","859989850455408642","7d79e45313c878ec78a0b34de60c69f3","860127021120327680","860300107266138112","860311173073391617","860312531407163393","860316615765876736","860156681401114626","860317260409257985","Qd_q0XF0Y10","860166160851099649","860190399180222466","860204548777889792","860211634886901760","1529799180366153_1532172110128860","860269305077870592","860287769960165376","860297098775982082","860162336727977985","10155014502490659_10155016027360659","1532221810123890_1533617433317661","10155015378740659_10155015420560659"]],["2017-05-04T03:08:33.000Z",0.55,["10155005822955659_10155006234215659","10155005822955659_10155006238455659","10155005609550659_10155006194705659","10155005822955659_10155006241065659","10155005822955659_10155006241655659","10155005822955659_10155006177605659","10155005114840659_10155006201270659","10155005609550659_10155006091430659","10155005609550659_10155006095520659","10155005609550659_10155006099105659","10155002652900659_10155006101040659","10155005822955659_10155006101600659","10155005609550659_10155006109155659","10155002652900659_10155006110655659","10155005822955659_10155006113965659","10155005609550659_10155006132275659","10155005609550659_10155006139910659","10155005822955659_10155006142495659","10155005609550659_10155006143850659","10154997175925659_10155006178085659","10155005822955659_10155006148580659","10155005609550659_10155006190080659","10155005114840659_10155006154345659","10155005822955659_10155006154825659","10155005114840659_10155006167935659","10155005609550659_10155006157700659","10155005114840659_10155006160225659","10155005609550659_10155006231175659","10155005609550659_10155006187295659","10155005822955659_10155006162850659"]],["2017-05-02T03:01:57.000Z",0.49,["874302750531694592","851862555752640513","851862767925637120","874318907250757634","874329266107936768","874335249144086531","851870647521341443","874107458871894021","851772861501059072","874355138969956352","874250856476139520","874274312253034496","874278730088280066","874356894428798977","851893814474264576","874666827904937985","851923766158520320","851891395493101568","874684725188845572","874685434911236098","874391730396708864","874396116737019909","874737533766311937","874799536073519104","874817322791313409","851892924115582977","874396860777091072","874551209625100288","874558005903335424","874609184905588736"]],["2017-04-11T03:04:21.000Z",0.54,["872880479300603905","872905370355855361","872914304227475460","872661418985877506","872662404416638976","872922590024794115","872923180117241856","872967240488034305","872980087943176193","872989868145741829","872997173008486402","872880235649392640","873003042869792790","872941776868433921","873004432853696512","872841099542450178","872767600647954435","872819121804726272","872940586894061568","872985706150350848","872762907746066432","872869944161165312","872880243824103424","872846343147999233","873015156883812353","872938894320390145","872655599145824256","873351602639384576","873352989515403264","ea4b7c58ceee69909aad70a8d25f46ef"]]]}';;


    var myArray = JSON.parse(myJSON);

    $.each(myArray['vector'],function(index, value){
        //Reduce the datetime to just YYYY-MM-DD
        myArray['vector'][index][0] = myArray['vector'][index][0].substring(0,10);
    });

$(document).ready(function(){


    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart:{
            zoomType:'x',
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false 
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title:{text:'Time'},
            tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        },
        yAxis: {
            max:1,
            min: 0,
            title:{ text: 'Focus of Conversations'},              
            plotBands: [{
                        color: 'black',
                        from: .5, // Start of the plot band
                        to: .51 // End of the plot band
                      }]
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Focus of Conversations Over Time'
        },

        series: [
        {
            type: 'scatter',
            data: myArray['vector'],
            marker: {  radius: 8 },
            showInLegend: false
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved. I converted my YYYY-MM-DD dates into seconds since the epoch and everything worked fine.

I changed this...

```
 $.each(myArray['vector'],function(index, value){
    //Reduce the datetime to just YYYY-MM-DD
    myArray['vector'][index][0] = myArray['vector'][index][0].substring(0,10);
});
```

to this...

```
$.each(myArray['vector'],function(index, value){
    //Reduce the datetime to just YYYY-MM-DD
    console.log(myArray['vector'][index][0].substring(0,10));
    myArray['vector'][index][0] = (new Date(myArray['vector'][index][0].substring(0,10))).getTime();
});
```